# Element type is invalid React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

```
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import { InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon } from '@material-ui/icons/InsertDriveFileOutlined';

<Grid item>
  <List>
    {policiesProcedures.map((doc, index) => (
      <ListItem button key={index}>
        <ListItemIcon>
          <InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon />
        </ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={doc.name} />
      </ListItem>
    ))}
  </List>
</Grid>;
```

This code is giving me error of

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components)
>   or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You
>   likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in,
>   or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

If I change it from List to something else like

or  it works fine.

Any clue what is happening wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show your import statements?

Comment: updated in the question

Comment: where are you importing InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon

Answer (score 3):

I suspect you have the wrong import statement.  If this is the default export than you export should look like

```
import InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon  from '../containers/InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon'
```

However, if it's not the default export, you should destructure it.

```
import {InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon}  from '../containers/InsertDriveFileOutlinedIcon'
```